# How to deal with very old DNS data

Tags: dns, browser-cache

I've got a website that I have moved from one server to another. Three months later there are still people arriving at the old server by entering the domain name in the browser.

What can I do about it? I've now put a message on the site that recommends users to press Ctrl+R in their browser. I've done that, because I assume that all DNS servers must have updated by now.

Is there anything else, I or they could do?

Comment: If Ctrl+R resolves the issue, than it is probably not the DNS issue.

Comment: @DusanBajic I assumed that the DNS information may be cached by the browser, is that incorrect?

Comment: I might be wrong. I just have rarely seen DNS TTL values so high that resolved names would still stay there after 3 months (I am not even sure if Chrome DNS cache for example respects TTL values), and I have often seen static web pages with huge max-age values. Do you actually see their visits in old webserver logs?

Comment: I see their visits in old log files. The content of the website is also slightly different. They and I automatically get an email sent when they register on the site and the text of this email is a bit different. Also they are registered on the old server. The logfiles on the old server only show a low number of visitors. Since I've changed the content of the old server now, I am at least save from wrong registrations happening, so the problem is solved for me, but still, it would be interesting to know the cause.

Comment: Three month seems like too much time for that to still happen. Perhaps old server is reachable by some other hostname that is still out there in people's bookmarks (you should be able to check that in webserver logs)